# asp.net get Oracle table_names inside a string list

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have a data-base of 2 tables EMP and DEPT (they're the default ones i got from when i created a sqldeveloper new user).
I connect to the data-base using OracleConnection. I create a OracleCommand to get the table_names:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT table_name FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS";
```

I create a list of string to store the names in it:

```
List<string> TableNamesList = new List<string>();
int index = 0;
```

Then i execute the DataReader and try to fill the list with the values in a while

```
 OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 while (reader.Read())
        {
            TableNamesList.Add(reader.GetString(index));
            index++;
        }
```

But i get the following error at the `TableNamesList.Add(reader.GetString(index));` line : **IndexOutOfRangeException: Invalid column index specified]**
How do i fix this please??

Comment: Just an FYI, it would be more efficient to get the table names using this query: `SELECT table_name FROM user_tables`

Comment: The Reader has only 1 column by x names.  So just remove index : TableNamesList.Add(reader[0].GetString());

Comment: oh, thank you both!